# How to get data from Mi band 2 and to parse a JSON?

Tags: android, json, fitness, xiaomi

Hi Is there any way to get steps and distance count from my Mi Band 2 and to parse a JSON hosted on 000 webhost? Or a 3rd party app to do so?